# forcing phonegap to use internal storage with fileTransfer download method

Tags: android, backbone.js, cordova

I am developing a phonegap applicaiton that downloads a file from the remote location like this:

```
var remoteFile=url+item.image;
    var localFileName=item.image;

       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
    function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(
        "dummy.html", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            var sPath = fileSystem.fullPath.replace("dummy.html","");
            var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
            fileEntry.remove();
            fileTransfer.download(
                remoteFile,
                sPath + localFileName,
                function(theFile) {
                    alert("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                    showLink(theFile.toURI());
                },
                function(error) {
                    console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                    console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                    console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                }
            );
        }, fail);
    }, fail);


    function fail(error) {
        alert(error.code);
    }
```

This downloads the files to a SD Card. To prevent external users from downloading the files, i want the app to forcefully store the files in device internal storage. What are my options?
Further, i need to retrieve the file (image) and display the same at some other point of time!

Comment: I need the same functionality. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: This code downloads files on SD card but on some devices it is download files in internal memory (wired behavior )